A person deleted his WhatsApp but still appears in my chats
A person said he deleted WhatsApp, but his contact still appears on my contact list and my chats.

It's unclear if that person deleted the WhatsApp app or his WhatsApp account. If it's the former, then please consult the duplicate link, but in short: uninstalling the app won't automatically delete the account, and thus the contact will still be visible on the contact list and the chat. If it's the latter, then please [edit] and clarify the question.

(@Community: If there's a better proposed duplicate, then feel free to let me know)
